# Proving that a function is strictly monotonic knowing that $|f(x)-x^2|\le2|x|$

Tags: calculus

Prove that the following real-valued function is strictly monotonic, knowing that 
$|f(x)-x^2|\le2|x|$.

I can't actually interpret the given data in a way that would produce the required conclusion, any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? (With term up we must be careful of not doing homework - I say we, everyone else, I try though!)

Comment: This is not a homework question, I stumbled upon this problem while browsing through a math forum.Anyhow, I tried squaring the inequality then rearranging the terms, but I got nothing useful.

Comment: You cant't. $f(x)=x^2$ is a function matching the condition and is not monotonic. Or think of $f(x)=x^2+x\cdot \mathbf 1_{\mathbb Q}(x)$, which is not monotonic anywhere.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein see my answer.

Comment: @AlecTeal Hagan had already addressed my comment in his edit (though his counterexample is discontinuous). Your answer still needs some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get $x^2-2|x|\le f(x)\le x^2+2|x|$ not by squaring but by noting:

$|a|<|b|$ (or indeed $\le$) is the same as $-b<a<b$

You can then see from the behavior at 0 there can be no such function

**Counter example**

As mentioned in the comments $f(x)=x^2$

**Missing bounds**
Even if it's for some range, like $[0,\infty)$ there can still be a function that isn't monotonic between the bounds. Eg $x(x-1)$ (look at the roots, that's how I spotted this)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein see edit

Answer (score 1):

It's not true: if $f(x) = x^2 - 2x$, then $f$ is not strictly increasing, but we have
$$|f(x) - x^2| = 2|x|$$
which satisfies the inequality.